# Showing comments in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

guys, I'm trying to realize viewing comments on internet portal and I'm using UITableView. Comments have structure like tree, for example:
- one comment
-- in reply: second comment
-- in reply: second comment
---in reply to reply ....

I've tried to use custom table view cell, but it isn't replacing uilabel like usual view. I've tried to make subtitled cell, but replacing isn't working with cell.textLabel.bounds.

Have you any ideas?
I have author name, comment level and comment text of all comments in NSDictionary.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a UILabel to your table view cell, then set the frame of the label according to the indent level. i.e. something like:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

myLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10*myIndentLevel, 0, 320-(10*myIndentLevel), 25.0)] autorelease];

myLabel.text = @"the comment text";

[cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
```

Answer (score 1):

For a basic structure you could use the `indentationLevel` property of `UITableViewCell`, which will indent the `contentView` (the amount it is indented depends on the `indentationWidth` property)